# Interactive Forms For User

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am creating an application which includes filling of lots of form rather chain of forms one after the other.

Can you give me a better way of creating wizard or forms? other than bootstrap modals which I am currently using?

Or can u provide some examples of UI where such forms are used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <section>
        <div class="wizard">
            <div class="wizard-inner">
                <div class="connecting-line"></div>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

                    <li role="presentation" class="active">
                        <a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" title="Step 1">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                        <a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" title="Step 2">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                        <a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step3" role="tab" title="Step 3">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                        <a href="#complete" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="complete" role="tab" title="Complete">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <form role="form">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="step1">
                        <h3>Step 1</h3>
                        <p>This is step 1</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step2">
                        <h3>Step 2</h3>
                        <p>This is step 2</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Previous</button></li>
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step3">
                        <h3>Step 3</h3>
                        <p>This is step 3</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Previous</button></li>
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default next-step">Skip</button></li>
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-info-full next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="complete">
                        <h3>Complete</h3>
                        <p>You have successfully completed all steps.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
   </div>
</div>




.wizard {
    margin: 20px auto;
    background: #fff;
}

    .wizard .nav-tabs {
        position: relative;
        margin: 40px auto;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border-bottom-color: #e0e0e0;
    }

    .wizard > div.wizard-inner {
        position: relative;
    }

.connecting-line {
    height: 2px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
    color: #555555;
    cursor: default;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

span.round-tab {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #e0e0e0;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
span.round-tab i{
    color:#555555;
}
.wizard li.active span.round-tab {
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #5bc0de;

}
.wizard li.active span.round-tab i{
    color: #5bc0de;
}

span.round-tab:hover {
    color: #333;
    border: 2px solid #333;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li {
    width: 25%;
}

.wizard li:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 46%;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #5bc0de;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.wizard li.active:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 46%;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #5bc0de;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li a {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

    .wizard .nav-tabs > li a:hover {
        background: transparent;
    }

.wizard .tab-pane {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.wizard h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
}

@media( max-width : 585px ) {

    .wizard {
        width: 90%;
        height: auto !important;
    }

    span.round-tab {
        font-size: 16px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
    }

    .wizard .nav-tabs > li a {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
    }

    .wizard li.active:after {
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        left: 35%;
    }
}




$(document).ready(function () {
    //Initialize tooltips
    $('.nav-tabs > li a[title]').tooltip();

    //Wizard
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {

        var $target = $(e.target);

        if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    $(".next-step").click(function (e) {

        var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
        $active.next().removeClass('disabled');
        nextTab($active);

    });
    $(".prev-step").click(function (e) {

        var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
        prevTab($active);

    });
});

function nextTab(elem) {
    $(elem).next().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
}
function prevTab(elem) {
    $(elem).prev().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
}
```

Code: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/form-wizard-using-tabs

Comment: can u suggest if i had to do same thing in React JS? how should I add Jquery to it?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the complete DEMO**. You need to make common validation script inside the same on click function to validate the form. This is using Bootstrap tabs.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".showMenu").on("click", function (e) {

            var nextTabToShow = $(this).attr("data-nextbtn");
            $('a[href="#' + nextTabToShow + '"]').trigger('click')


            });
            $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('hide.bs.tab', function (e) {
            var $old_tab = $($(e.target).attr("href"));
            var $new_tab = $($(e.relatedTarget).attr("href"));

            if ($new_tab.index() < $old_tab.index()) {
            $old_tab.css('position', 'relative').css("right", "0").show();
            $old_tab.animate({ "right": "-100%" }, 300, function () {
                $old_tab.css("right", 0).removeAttr("style");
            });
        }
        else {
            $old_tab.css('position', 'relative').css("left", "0").show();
            $old_tab.animate({ "left": "-100%" }, 300, function () {
                $old_tab.css("left", 0).removeAttr("style");
            });
        }
    }).on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
        var $new_tab = $($(e.target).attr("href"));
        var $old_tab = $($(e.relatedTarget).attr("href"));

        if ($new_tab.index() > $old_tab.index()) {
            $new_tab.css('position', 'relative').css("right", "-2500px");
            $new_tab.animate({ "right": "0" }, 500);
        }
        else {
            $new_tab.css('position', 'relative').css("left", "-2500px");
            $new_tab.animate({ "left": "0" }, 500);
        }        
    });

  })
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs hidden" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active">
          <a href="#1" aria-controls="1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"></a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#2" aria-controls="2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"></a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#3" aria-controls="3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="1">
          <h4>Step 1</h4>
          <div class="text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn continue showMenu" data-nextbtn="2">
              Continue <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="2">
          <h4>Step 2</h4>
          <div class="text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn continue showMenu" data-nextbtn="3">
              Continue <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn back showMenu" data-nextbtn="1">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Back
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="3">
          <h4>Step 3</h4>
          <div class="text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn continue">
              Submit
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn back showMenu" data-nextbtn="2">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Back
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
```